Chrysanthemum dying
This is the second year i have had my 5 pots of mums.
Last year they all went well, had to water very regularly to stop them wilting.
This year 4 pots are doing well, but one is a bit weary.
I am Watering every dry day and taking the dead off, also using miracle grow, which they all loved last year.
Please can anyone tell me how to get the weary plant back to good health.
Thanks
